# My second drop-down list isn't working

Tags: select, drop-down-menu

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToNewPage ()
    {
        var url = document.getElementById('list').value;
        if(url != 'none') {
            window.location = url;
            }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<header>
<nav>
<a href="gems.html">
    <img src="gems-logo.png" alt="Gems Logo" height="120" width="150">
</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="gems.html">Home</a></li>
<select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
    <option value='none' selected></option>
    <option value="available-services.html">Available Services</option>
    <option value="construction.html">Construction Cleaning</option>
    <option value="maintenance.html">Maintenance Cleaning</option>
    <option value="residential.html">Residential Cleaning</option>
    <option value="office.html">Office Cleaning</option>
    </select>
<input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />
<select name="drop" id="drop" accesskey="target">
    <option value='none' selected></option>
    <option value="about-gems.html">About Gems</option>
    <option value="spring-fall.html">Spring/Fall Information</option>
    <option value="application.html">Apply</option>
    <option value="pricing.html">Pricing</option>
    <option value="contact-us.html">Contact Us</option>
    </select>
<input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />

</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

The two button types are yellow in notepad++ and the first drop down works but the second one is allowing me to select an option but the button isn't letting me go to the page that I select. I've tried to rename the button and to rename the button inside the code for example button1 but all that gave me was a type of search bar.

Comment: I realize that your code is just a snippet but you are missing a few HTML tags (both opening and closing) which make it hard for anyone to help you.   Can you edit your code with the full page of HTML.  Just for an example, I see an opening <UL> but no cleaning </UL>.  Also, you cannot have the same name/id for your selects.

Comment: closed all the ones that needed to be and I tried to rename the select list and still doesn't work

Comment: Can you edit your above post and put the new html into it?

Comment: I just updated it with the entire code

Comment: Just got off the train.  Let me get home and I'll take a look.

Comment: Alright Thank you

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood my first comment.  When I said you cannot have the same name/id I was not saying an element cannot have the same name='somename' and id='somename' I was saying two elements on the page cannot have the same name and id as another element.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to add that into the code, but i tried that and didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I have sorted it for you but you are trying to do something you cannot do.

1. As I said, your dropdowns cannot have the same ID as any other element in the DOM or JS cannot find it.
2. Having two buttons call the same function expecting them to do different things is mental.

I have provided a modified version of your code below that works.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var goToNewPage1 = function()
            {
                var url = document.getElementById('list1').value;
                if(url != 'none') {
                    window.location = url;
                }
            }

            var goToNewPage2 = function()
            {
                var url = document.getElementById('list2').value;
                if(url != 'none') {
                    window.location = url;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <a href="gems.html">
                    <img src="gems-logo.png" alt="Gems Logo" height="120" width="150">
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="gems.html">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
                <select name="list1" id="list1" accesskey="target">
                    <option value="none" selected=""></option>
                    <option value="available-services.html">Available Services</option>
                    <option value="construction.html">Construction Cleaning</option>
                    <option value="maintenance.html">Maintenance Cleaning</option>
                    <option value="residential.html">Residential Cleaning</option>
                    <option value="office.html">Office Cleaning</option>
                </select>
                <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()">
                <select name="list2" id="list2" accesskey="target">
                    <option value="none" selected=""></option>
                    <option value="about-gems.html">About Gems</option>
                    <option value="spring-fall.html">Spring/Fall Information</option>
                    <option value="application.html">Apply</option>
                    <option value="pricing.html">Pricing</option>
                    <option value="contact-us.html">Contact Us</option>
                </select>
                <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()">
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```